# Changing column value in ultrawingrid

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an ultrawingrid from Infragistics which binds itself to a dataset. What I want to do is, for one of the columns I want to apply a converter. 
That means, for a column that displays abbreviations for example, I want to display full names for each. 
Is there a nice way to do such this in here. I know in WPF I could use converters.

Answer (score 3):

In your InitializeLayout event you should place something like this

```
    Infragistics.Win.ValueList vlAbbrevs = new Infragistics.Win.ValueList();
    vlAbbrevs.ValueListItems.Add("F", "Female");
    vlAbbrevs.ValueListItems.Add("M", "Male");
    vlAbbrevs.Key = "_ABBVS_";
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Gender"].ValueList = vlAbbrevs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DataFilter.  The following is an overview of data filters: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/current/CLR2.0/?page=WinGrid_About_Data_Filters.html

The following blog post has an example:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/winforms/articles/using-an-wingrid-datafilter-to-convert-strings-to-bools-and-vice-versa-for-a-checkbox-column.aspx